# Copy "Text" column content only from logcat view

Tags: android, logcat, ddms

Does anybody know of a way, or something that could ease the process of manually removing the extra strings, to get only the content of the "Text" column in the logcat view when copying the logcat content?

Comment: doesn't `logcat -v raw -d` do what you want?

Comment: My question was within the context of DDMS (to be exact Eclipse's DDMS). Your answer operates within the console.

Comment: kindly have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems not possible, but I've drawn an attention to it through android issues portal:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77883&thanks=77883&ts=1413891569

Hopefully it will be implemented soon enough, as it woudl be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve that:

**The First Way,** if you have multiple lines:

- copy your text to Notepad++ or any editor that uses Regex.
- press ctrl+f and choose `Replace` tab.
- use a Regex format in order to remove all the unnecessary tags info, for example in the case of `System.out` messages, the Regex formula will be:

  `\d*-\d* \d*:\d*:\d*\.\d*: I\/System\.out\(\d*\):`
  if the messages are like:
  `03-14 14:44:17.557: I/System.out(18293):`
- finaly, use this formula in **[find what]** field and use a white space in the **[Replace with]** field, and don't forget to choose **`Regular Expression`** choice in the (*search mode*) field.

**The second way,** if you have a single line of log: [as described here](http://www.stevenmarkford.com/how-to-copy-text-from-logcat-to-clipboard-in-eclipse/):

1. Right click on the line in Logcat which you wish to copy text from
2. Click “find similar messages”
3. In the window that pops up the text is contained in the field “by Log Message:”
4. This text can now be copied via Ctrl+C

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to paste it into a text editor that supports multiline editing, like VSCode or Sublime. Then, you can middle-mouse drag to multiselect the start of all the lines and delete them.